# php chained functions in classes

Tags: php, oop

What is going on in this statement?

```
$this->load->view("index.php");
```

I've seen this syntax in CodeIgniter and elsewhere where the code is inside a class, hence "$this", and it is referencing "load" or some other method which is then pointing to a method/function it looks like.

Can someone explain to me what "load" is in this? Not in the CodeIgniter context but general PHP. How would i write a class that allows for this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

class myObject {

    private $x = 0;

    function amethod()
    {

       function embeddedFunc()
       {

            $this->x += 7;

            return $this->x;
       }

       return embeddedFunc();
    }
}

$object = new myObject();

echo $object->amethod->embeddedFunc();

?>
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around what's actually happening when i see this.

Comment: Load is not a method in your example. It is a property that, if I had to guess, holds an object with a method `view()`.

Comment: This is the CI object, load is the controller, view is the method. What you're doing is not following this pattern. In your case, un-nest that function and just put it at the same level as the other one then call it $object->embeddedFunc()

Answer (score 1):

In this case load is a property of the class that is an object that has a `view()` function. For example:

```
class test {
    public $load;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load = new test2();
    }
    public function step1() {
        $this->load->step3('Updated text');
    }
}
class test2 {
    public function step3($display_text) {
        echo $display_text;
    }
}
$tester = new test();
$tester->step1();
```

Since `load` is an instance of an object you can go ahead and run a function of that instance. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, *$this->* is required to access a class member variable. It's a bit confusing, that you have to write *this->* strictly, but other hand you don't have to declare it.

```
 class Foo {

   function bar() {

      $this->myVariable = 8;   // this is OK

   } // bar() 

 } // class Foo
```

So *$this->load->view()* refers to the current object's *load* property, which holds an object which has view() method. Train your eye to cut the leading *this->* and train your hand to write it always. Just as you've already learned to write leading '$' mark always.